# Postgresql foreign data wrapper raises error when retrieving any foreign table data from SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, freetds, foreign-data-wrapper

I set up foreign data wrapper in postgresql using freetds to connect to SQL Server and installed the `tds_fdw` extension in postgresql, but when selecting data from a foreign table, the code always raises this DB-Library error:

> DB #: 4075 error:
>   The USE database statement failed because the database collation Persian_100_CI_AI is not recognized by older client drivers. Try upgrading the client operating system or applying a service update to the database client software, or use a different collation. See SQL Server Books Online for more information on changing collations

I delve into net and config freets.conf file located in `/etc/freetds`

```
[global]
        # TDS protocol version
;       tds version = 8.0

        # Whether to write a TDSDUMP file for diagnostic purposes
        # (setting this to /tmp is insecure on a multi-user system)
;       dump file = /tmp/freetds.log
;       debug flags = 0xffff

        # Command and connection timeouts
;       timeout = 10
;       connect timeout = 10

        # If you get out-of-memory errors, it may mean that your client
        # is trying to allocate a huge buffer for a TEXT field.
        # Try setting 'text size' to a more reasonable limit
        text size = 64512
        client charset = UTF-8
# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
        host = symachine.domain.com
        port = 5000
        tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[mssql]
        host = 192.168.x.x
        port = 1433
        tds version = 7.1
```

here is my sql code in postgres

```
CREATE SERVER prs_server
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER tds_fdw
OPTIONS (servername '192.168.x.x', port '1433',database 'prs_bpms', tds_version '7.1', msg_handler 'notice');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR postgres
SERVER prs_server
OPTIONS (username 'bpms', password 'xxxx');

CREATE FOREIGN TABLE prs_table (
    FirstName varchar null,
       LastName varchar nuul,
       SSN varchar not null

)
SERVER prs_server 
OPTIONS (query 'SELECT top 10 [FirstName],[LastName],[SSN] FROM [dbo].[prs_Personnel] ');


SELECT * FROM prs_table;
```

And also I need to use where clause but backslash escape character like `'select from where ssn = \'1234\''` doesn't work and gives syntax error.

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/FreeTDS/freetds/issues/74), you need to use `tds_version` of at least `7.3` to connect successfully. Try changing it in your `CREATE SERVER` statement.

Answer (score 0):

according to this issue https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw/issues/56
I think user 'bpms' does not have grant permission your table.